# Slick: How does autoInc work in the MultiDBCakeExample example?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to understand how Slick works and how to use it... and looking at their examples in GitHub I ended up with this code snippet in [MultiDBCakeExample.scala](https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBCakeExample.scala):

```
trait PictureComponent { this: Profile => //requires a Profile to be mixed in...
  import profile.simple._ //...to be able import profile.simple._

  object Pictures extends Table[(String, Option[Int])]("PICTURES") {
    ...

    def * = url ~ id

    val autoInc = url returning id into { case (url, id) => Picture(url, id) }

    def insert(picture: Picture)(implicit session: Session): Picture = {
      autoInc.insert(picture.url)
    }
  }
}
```

I suppose the `*` method returns a row in the table, while `autoInc` should somehow provide functionality for automatically incrementing the entity id... but to be honest I've some trouble in understanding this piece of code. What does `returning` refer to? What does `autoInc` return?

I looked at the Slick documentation but I was unable to find helpful information. Any help would be really appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that `autoInc` can be confusing I will provide you a working example (please note that my DB is PostgreSQL so I need that hack with `forInsert` in order to make Postgresql driver increment auto-inc values).

```
case class GeoLocation(id: Option[Int], latitude: Double, longitude: Double, altitude: Double)

/**
 * Define table "geo_location".
 */
object GeoLocations extends RichTable[GeoLocation]("geo_location") {
  def latitude = column[Double]("latitude")
  def longitude = column[Double]("longitude")
  def altitude = column[Double]("altitude")

  def * = id.? ~ latitude ~ longitude ~ altitude <> (GeoLocation, GeoLocation.unapply _)
  def forInsert = latitude ~ longitude ~ altitude <> ({ (lat, long, alt) => GeoLocation(None, lat, long, alt) },
    { g: GeoLocation => Some((g.latitude, g.longitude, g.altitude)) })
}
```

My RichTable is an abstract class in order to not declare ids for each Table I have but just extend this:

```
abstract class RichTable[T](name: String) extends Table[T](name) {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  val byId = createFinderBy(_.id)

}
```

and use it like:

```
GeoLocations.forInsert.insert(GeoLocation(None, 22.23, 25.36, 22.22))
```

Since you pass `None` for `id`, it will be generated automatically by PostgreSql driver when Slick inserts this new entity.
I have a few weeks since I started with Slick and I really recommend it!

**UPDATE**: If you want to not use `forInsert` projections, another approach is the following - in my case the entity is `Address`.

Create sequence for each table on schema creation:

```
session.withTransaction {
  DBSchema.tables.drop
  DBSchema.tables.create
  // Create schemas to generate ids too.
  Q.updateNA("create sequence address_seq")
}
```

Define a method to generate the ids using sequences (I defined this `once` in `RichTable` class:

```
  def getNextId(seqName: String) = Database { implicit db: Session =>
    Some((Q[Int] + "select nextval('" + seqName + "_seq') ").first)
  }
```

and in the mapper override `insert` method like:

```
  def insert(model : Address) = Database { implicit db: Session =>
    *.insert(model.copy(id = getNextId(classOf[Address].getSimpleName())))
  }
```

And now, you can pass `None` when you do an insert and this methods will do a nice work for you...

Comment: ... and what's if I don't want an auto-incremented ID? For example, I could generate an entity ID by hashing the email address... does your example work for both auto-inc and custom ID?

Comment: Yes, instead of passing `None` you pass your actual id like `GeoLocations.forInsert.insert(GeoLocation(Some(134), 22.23, 25.36, 22.22))`

Comment: What can be done when tables are larger? maybe 15-20 columns... the `forInsert` method becomes a monster!

Comment: @alexBrand In Slick 2.x, there is no longer a need for `forInsert`