Slick postgresql Inserting Query with AutoIncr
I'd like to work with psql from scala.In this purpose i started using slick. But i get a problem while trying to insert row to a class define with an O.AutoInc property:
Here is a simplified example of my problem :
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class User(id: Option[Int], first: String, last: String)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def first = column[String]("first")
  def last = column[String]("last")
  def * = (id.?, first, last) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}


object DatabaseManager {
  val db=Database.forConfig("mydb")
  val users = TableQuery[Users]

  def createSchema(): Unit = {
    val setup=DBIO.seq(
      users.schema.createIfNotExists
    )
    Await.result(db.run(setup),40.seconds)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    createSchema()
    Await.result(db.run(users+=User(None,"Step","Zei")),30.seconds)
  }
}

The createSchema() methods works, and im well connected to my psql db, and i get the following log :
 Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, Step, Zei).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$SingleInsertAction.$anonfun$run$15(JdbcActionComponent.scala:522)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:425)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef.withPreparedStatement$(JdbcBackend.scala:420)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:489)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl.preparedInsert(JdbcActionComponent.scala:513)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$SingleInsertAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:519)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcProfileAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:30)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcProfileAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:27)
    at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:275)
    at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:275)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I well understand it, but why the O.AutoIncr property doesn't its job by increment the id field ?
Can it be due to my DB config  application.conf ?
mydb = {
  connectionPool = "HikariCP"
  dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
  properties = {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase"
    user = "myuser"
    password = "mysecretpassword"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}

I was expecting that he is trying to insert Row (1,Step,Zei)

This might give some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739182/slick-how-does-autoinc-work-in-the-multidbcakeexample-example. Especially I think you cannot add a User, you'll have to use a tuple without any id I believe.
